# How do I render a file (image) from server-side on angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have managed to save a file in the database using my java server. Now I want to display that file ,which is of MIME type image/jpg, in my Angular side.

The problem is when I try and send a GET request, I receive the exact image correctly. I do not know how to display it the html page. 
Below you can see how I retrieve the image.

```java
@GetMapping(path="/{id}", produces ="image/jpg")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getById(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(certService.getFile(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Also I receive a Http failure during parsing for http://localhost/certificate/131 error when I call the above function.

Can you please help me on how can I display the image on Angular?

Comment: Dose it work `<img src="http://localhost/certificate/131" />`?

Comment: Try with the exact image URL. For example http://localhost/certificate/xxx.png

Comment: Thank you!! It worked. @ChunbinLi

Comment: @LejdiPrifti Ok , I will post my answer, please accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the image link(http://localhost/certificate/131) on the `img` tag

**Example**

```
 <img src="http://localhost/certificate/131" />
```

Comment: This answer works if we don't have security. What should we do if we have security implemented?